# stacking 3 variables for kmeans scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, k-means

I have 3 variable that i want to fit into a kmeans model. One is the TFIDF vector, One is the Count vector and the third one is the number of words in a document (sentence_list_len).

Here is my code:

```
vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, max_df=0.9, stop_words='english', decode_error='ignore')
vectorized=vectorizer.fit_transform(sentence_list)

count_vectorizer=CountVectorizer(min_df=1, max_df=0.9, stop_words='english', decode_error='ignore')
count_vectorized=count_vectorizer.fit_transform(sentence_list)

sentence_list_len # for each document, how many words are there

km=KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, init='k-means++',n_init=10, verbose=1)
km.fit(vectorized)
```

How do i fit the 3 variables into km.fit? specifically how do i stack all three of them and feed it to km.fit()?

Answer (score 0):

Simply concatenate your vectors. See `numpy.concatenate` or `numpy.vstack` / `numpy.hstack`. However, be aware that kmeans **does not work well** with high dimensional data and that it will probably ignore "small" features. You have three types of features in different scales, this will heavily affect clustering results. In general kmeans is not a good approach to the NLP clustering tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The official way is to use a [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html#featureunion-combining-feature-extractors):

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion

tfidf =TfidfVectorizer()
cvect = CountVectorizer()
features = FeatureUnion([('cvect', cvect), ('tfidf', tfidf)])
X = features.fit_transform(sentence_list)
```

Comment: how is this different from this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496014/does-it-make-sense-to-use-both-countvectorizer-and-tfidfvectorizer-as-feature-ve/27496255?noredirect=1#comment44661820_27496255 where you used hstack instead?

Comment: No big difference. There you join the transformed matrices and here you use directly the vectorizers. Also this can be used in a Pipeline, so it is easier to use, for example in crossvaligdation. Also I thought at the time that, as you were still learning, it would be better that you see whats going on behind the scenes.